# I get "Session Expired" when logging in to our site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, omniauth

Sorry for double posting probably same question but I don't think I've explained the question much on the previous one. Here's an easier to understand question:

The site I'm working on uses Devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/) and Omniauth (https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) to allow users to logon via Twitter. It works well when it's used in browsers.

This is how to reproduce the problem:

1. User is using Twitter's IOS app
2. User clicks on a link of our site that was embedded in a tweet
3. Twitter opens our site via UIWebView
4. Our site requires the user to login via Twitter
5. The app executes Safari and redirects to Twitter's login portal, prompting the user to login
6. When the users submits the form, it redirects him back to our site and throws an error: "Session Expired"

Any ideas why this is happening? Or anyone experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there has been any change to this, I posted this question here that has more interaction https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/9711.